# How do I get reason of a merge conflict after executing merge/rebase?

Tags: git, merge

Git merge/rebase show reason of conflict:

```
CONFLICT (delete/modify): res/layout/dialog_item.xml deleted in dialog and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of res/layout/dialog_item.xml left in tree.
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/DialogAdapter.java
```

How get it after executing git merge/rebase?

`git status` only show part of this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the conflict files and search for the markers

usually they look like this

```
>>>>>>> HEAD

<<<<<<BRANCH
```

Comment: It is a pity that cannot be done without parsing files